# How do I get my program to continue after an if statement

Tags: python

Beginner in python here. I am trying to make a program that takes the first 20 English numbers and and translate them to Spanish (or vice versa, based on what the user chooses). I wanted to include a provision that would tell the user that the option they chose is invalid, then prompt them to pick a valid one. When I run my program, it gives the message that the number is invalid, but doesn't allow them to pick a new number. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
i = int(input('To go from English to Spanish, press 1. Press 2 for Spanish to English translation'))
if i != 1 or 2:
    print('Invalid statement. Please print either 1 or 2 for translation.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need it to do in this way:

```
while True:
    i = int(input('To go from English to Spanish, press 1. Press 2 for Spanish to English translation'))

    if i != 1 and i!=2:
        print('Invalid statement. Please print either 1 or 2 for translation.')
    if i==1 or i==2:
        break
```

Comment: Put `input` statement right after `while` and do an `else: break`. Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: You can see Harun's answer

Comment: Also, `if i==1 or i==2` is just a negation of `if i != 1 and i!=2`. That is what `else` closure is for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while` loop to re-ask the user to input a new number as following:

```
while True:
    i = int(input('To go from English to Spanish, press 1. ' 
                  'Press 2 for Spanish to English translation'))

    if i in (1, 2):
      break

    print('Invalid statement. Please print either 1 or 2 for translation.')
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to make your code work regardless of entering an `integer` value, you need to wrap it in `try/except` block.

```
while True:

    try:
      i = int(input('To go from English to Spanish, press 1. ' 
                  'Press 2 for Spanish to English translation'))

      if i in [1,2]:
        break
    
    except:
      print('Invalid statement. Please print either 1 or 2 for translation.')

print('Here we go...')
```

Here's a repl.it link: https://replit.com/@HarunYlmaz/OverjoyedWoodenModels#main.py

Comment: There is no `is in` operator. It's just `in`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych You're right. I fixed that typo.